# Multiplied differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to get $x(t),y(t)$ solutions for "product differential equations"  (dotted on $t$):

$$\dot x \dot y= xy,\; \dot y^2-\dot x ^2= 1;$$

we have by solving quadratics

$$ (2\dot y^2, 2 \dot x^2)= + 1 \pm \sqrt{1+4x^2y^2} ,\; - 1 \pm \sqrt{1+4x^2y^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can eliminate $y$.

$$\dot x^2-\dot y^2=1\to \dot x^4-\dot x^2\dot y^2=\dot x^2\to \dot x^4-x^2y^2=\dot x^2$$

and

$$y^2=\frac{\dot x^4-\dot x^2}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Hint too broad for me :)

Comment: @Narasimham: ??? After elimination you get a "normal" ODE in $x$. It is a common trick to eliminate one function while increasing the order of the equation.